# How to reset JDBC connection from the datasource connection pool on WebLogic after some seconds

Tags: weblogic, connection-pooling

Is it possible to configure WebLogic's JDBC connection pool to reset established connections after a certain amount of time has elapsed, even if the connection is actively in use?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to configure JDBC connection reset